# Populate treeview using only specific XML nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net, treeview

I know how to pupulate a treeview using XML nodes however I'm not sure on how to populate a treeview with nodes only found under a certain parent node of an XML file..

example:

I want a tree view to display only nodes listed under the node TreeViewItems... whilst disregarding ...

```
<MyXmlFile>

<AllOtherStuff>
              <bla1>blabla<Bla1>
              <bla2>blablabla<Bla2>
              <bla3>blablablabla<Bla3>
</AllOtherStuff>

<TreeviewItems>
              <item1>DWG file</item1>
              <item2>DOC file</item2>
              <item3>PDF file</item3>
</TreeviewItems>
</MyXmlFile>
```

the following is the code I use to populate a treeview with the entire contents of an XML file...

```
    Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
    Dim xmlnode As XmlNode
    Dim fs As New FileStream("tree.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    xmldoc.Load(fs)
    xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes(1)
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name))
    Dim tNode As TreeNode
    tNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0)
    AddNode(xmlnode, tNode)
```

EDDIT:

```
Private Sub AddNode(ByVal inXmlNode As XmlNode, ByVal inTreeNode As TreeNode)
    Dim xNode As XmlNode
    Dim tNode As TreeNode
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
    Dim i As Integer
    If inXmlNode.HasChildNodes Then
        nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes
        For i = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes(i)
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xNode.Name))
            tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)
            AddNode(xNode, tNode)
        Next
    Else
        inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you expand AddNode() - I'd like to see how you actually add the XML to the treeview

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TreeviewItems")` will give you the node, then just do a foreach on it's children.